# Obtaining calculated field valid value from ssrs report

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

I have a report in which I have a parameter that has the following Valid Values: value set to a query field and label set to the following calculated field ::

=Fields!RestaurantCode.Value & " - " & Fields!Name.Value

I then obtain in c# the valid values from the report (after it's been deployed), if I set the value and label to query fields everything works fine. However with a calculated field, ReportingService2010 .GetItemParameters returns null for the ValidValues.

I've tested the report and correctly see the calculated field displayed *in the report*. I've tried referencing only a field in the calculated field expression (=Fields!RestaurantCode.Value) and ValidValues is still null.

How can I correctly obtain a calculated field through .GetItemParameters ValidValues?

EDIT: forRendering parameter of the .GetItemParameters function is set to true

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a valid scenario for SSRS - mixing Query values and static Labels for a single Parameter.  I would move that calculation to the query as a new field.

Comment: I did end up just making a second stored procedure that simply returned the 'calculated field' I wanted so I could use it as a query field, but my question remains why couldn't you get calculated fields in validvalues? I haven't read anywhere that it could'nt be done and I can't quite see why you couldn't .... it annoys me, I want to know , it's frustrating! lol - +1 because even though I did it before you posted it is what I ended up doing, but it isn't the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Trust me - after 10 years of working with this product, this is one of the last things to get annoyed about ...